Why is it OK to pour the wort into the fermenter as opposed to siphoning it WRT aerating?
My brew instructions say "pour or siphon wort into sanitized fermenter". I've been skeptical of that because it would splash a bit going into a 5G bucket. Is aerating not a problem right after cooling off the wort? Or should I always choose the siphon option?

Aeration is actually required after cooling the wort. In this respect, the more you splash, the better off your beer will be (when transferring from kettle to fermenter).
Yeast cannot build cell walls without available oxygen, and you want the yeast to be able to grow and multiply during the initial hours of the fermentation. In practice, the yeast will absorb and utilize all available oxygen.
After fermentation gets going, you absolutely want to minimize exposing your beer to oxygen.

OMG. I poured it but I went out of my way to slide it down the side of the bucket for both the wort and the additional water. OK, next batch I just dump it in. That's easier and according to you better for the yeast. Thx bud.

You should also spent at least 5 minutes stirring/splashing the cool wort as well. With this technique, you can almost get sufficient oxygen in solution to make the yeast completely happy. Or you can get a diffuser and use pure oxygen (this is what the pros do, and there are relatively inexpensive versions of this for home brewing).
